# Salesforce - HubSpot API calls

Tags: salesforce, hubspot

in my current company we are using Salesforce and HubSpot, and we have synchronized Contacts and Leads.

HubSpot does around 7000-8000 daily api calls, but I do not know what is the frequency HubSpot connects to Salesforce, or if there are some ways to reduce this number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce limits its API calls with the edition and licenses you have see this link
(https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm) 
and for reducing the api calls from Hubspot end  follow this link 
(http://knowledge.hubspot.com/salesforce-integration-user-guide/how-to-adjust-your- salesforce-api-call-limit)

Comment: Yes, we can limit the calls, but then the sync will be stop.

I am not talking about limiting api calls to some number, but reduce the call number, "improve", so the sync will do the same but using less requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you go over you're API call quota, Salesforce will send you an automated email letting you know of the overage.

The usage limit for the lowest edition of Salesforce is 15,000. If you're currently at 8k/day, I wouldn't worry yet.